# libGDX interface cannot be applied error

Tags: android, libgdx

I would like to use interfaces in libGDX.

I get an error in `AndroidLauncher` before compile.

It says for this line:
`initialize(new MyGdxGame(actionResolverAndroid), config);` `.... cannot be applied`

You can try, run whole code here: https://github.com/kovacsakos/gdx-interfaces

[image]

Comment: I think it is because your `MyGdxGame` is a `Screen`, not a `Game` or `ApplicationListener`

Comment: Yes, but `Screen` is necessary to use `render()` method. Other parts need this.

Comment: Post updated with error message!

Comment: It's exactly the error I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub repo has been updated, you can see working code in it.